# Fail to find the dnn implementation for LSTM

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to run a simple LSTM model with following code

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32,
                                       input_shape=x_train_single.shape[-2:]))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1))

model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(), loss='mae')

single_step_history = model.fit(train_data_single, epochs=EPOCHS,
                                        steps_per_epoch=EVALUATION_INTERVAL)
```

The error happened when it trying to fit the model

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnknownError:  [_Derived_]  Fail to find the dnn implementation.
     [[{{node CudnnRNN}}]]
     [[sequential/lstm/StatefulPartitionedCall]] [Op:__inference_distributed_function_3107]
```

There's another error like this

```
2020-02-22 19:08:06.478567: W tensorflow/core/kernels/data/cache_dataset_ops.cc:820] The calling 
iterator did not fully read the dataset being cached. In order to avoid unexpected truncation of the 
dataset, the partially cached contents of the dataset will be discarded. This can happen if you have 
an input pipeline similar to `dataset.cache().take(k).repeat()`. You should use 
`dataset.take(k).cache().repeat()` instead.
```

I tried all methods on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54473254/cudnnlstm-unknownerror-fail-to-find-the-dnn-implementation) which doesn't work for me

my envrionment is

```
 tensorflow-gpu 2.0
 CUDA v10
 CuDNN 7.6.5
```

**Solution**

OK.. I found that I didn't have the latest Nvidia driver, so I upgraded, and works

Answer (score 1):

Answering here for the benefit of the community even if the user has provided the solution.

Upgrading Nvidia driver to the latest has resolved the issue.

You can update NVIDIA manually from [here](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us) here by selecting the product details and OS, you’re going to have to download the most recent drivers from their website. You’ll then have to run the installer and overwrite the old driver.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try below

import tensorflow as tf

physical_devices = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], enable=True)